# Jackson skip field serialization - custom configuration

Tags: kotlin, serialization, jackson, rabbitmq

i have custom jackson configuration in `kotlin`:

```
@Configuration
class JacksonConfiguration {

    @Bean
    fun objectMapper(): com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper = jacksonObjectMapper()
            .setSerializationInclusion(JsonInclude.Include.NON_EMPTY)
            .apply {
                registerModules(customJavaTimeModule(), KotlinModule())
                configure(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, false)
            }
}

private fun customJavaTimeModule() = JavaTimeModule().apply {
    addSerializer(String::class.java, StringSerializerTypeHandler())
}

private class StringSerializerTypeHandler : JsonSerializer<String?>() {

    @Throws(IOException::class, JsonProcessingException::class)
    override fun serialize(value: String?, jgen: JsonGenerator?, provider: SerializerProvider?) {
        var outputValue: String = value.toString()

        if (!value.isNullOrEmpty()) {
            // logic for changing the string - removing diacritics
            jgen?.writeString(outputValue)
        } else {
            //provider?. // what here?
           // jgen?.writeString(value)
           // dont serialize the field at all - just skip it
        }
    }
}
```

What's important is that i do not want that field to be serialized at all when the field value is `null` or `empty`.
I can not get rid of `else` block - then I will have error:

> Can not write a field name, expecting a value

I want to set this logic globally.

Answer (score 0):

Solution 1:

I had to override this method:

```
override fun isEmpty(provider: SerializerProvider?, value: String?): Boolean {
    return value.isNullOrEmpty()
 }
```

Then i can get rid of `else` block.